# How to make Jenkins build pushed code and pull requests from Github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to find the right configuration so Jenkins starts a job when:

```
1. code is pushed to Github
2. a pull request it made
```

I've found the Github and Github Pull Request Builder plugins to be very helpful, but I cannot get both #1 and #2 working concurrently.

It may have to do with the refspec I set in the Source Code Management section. #1 requires a refspec of    `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` while #2 requires a refspec of `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`.

I've tried using two repositories within the same section, but only one or the other builds, not both.

Is there a plugin or a specific configuration I can use that will build both pushes and pull requests?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify both refspecs by simply separating them with a space:

```
+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

...as described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

Then configure multiple branch specifiers. I have:

```
*/master
${sha1}
:refs/heads/v\d*\.\d*
```

This builds, PRs, master and my release candidate branches.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to setup Both in one job then you may have to change your requirement little bit.

Either
You create 2 jobs in same jenkins for different work.

OR
Use pull request builder and set configuration to merge the code after build, this way you achieve both.

If your repo have pushes other than pull request then you will have to create 2 jobs.

Comment: That is currently my setup. I have two projects, one that builds pushes and  one that builds pull requests. I was hoping to keep things contained in a single project, but it looks like it's not possible. I also don't want to merge the code after every build since we code review before merge.